# can't get pgadmin4 to launch

Tags: debian, apt, postgresql

I have Debian 10 with KDE plasma. I installed PGAdmin4 and when I try to open it I immediately get this error:

```
Fatal Error
Failed to open the system default web browser. Is one installed?.
```

I am new to linux and I have no idea how to fix this. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling and still get this error. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The default web browser in Debian's KDE environment is Konqueror. Check that a default web browser is set.

```
$ xdg-settings get default-web-browser
```

From the debian wiki for KDE: Under System Settings -> Default Applications -> Web Browser, change Open http and https URLs to "in the following browser:" and enter the path of the browser's executable (for example, /usr/bin/iceweasel).

If you need to configure the default browser for the system, use:

```
# update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
```

That will prompt you with the options to set. Select the one you want to use. If that one still doesn't work, run the command again and try a different option (if there is another one available).

If there isn't another option available for you to choose from. Try installing another web browser like Chrome and setting the default to that.

Comment: I tired that but I still get the same error. It shows in all 3 places (xdg-settings, update-alternatives, and system settings > applications > web browser) that my web browser is defined as firefox-esr. For some reason, pgadmin4 isn't recognizing this.

Comment: Try setting it to Chrome/Chromium. And try again